# Possible to embed a C++ dx renderer in a C# app without using managed c++?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, directx, managed-c++

I have a renderer written in C++ and directX.  I now want to write a (level / scene / UI) editor and if possible / realistic I would prefer to write the interface to my editor in C#/.net

Is this at all feasible, without going down a route of managed c++?  Can I expose the necessary interface from my renderer to a C# app, without managed c++?

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on how you wrote it ... If you wrote the renderer as a COM object then you should have no troubles.  As a DLL using C calls I believe is still relatively easy as well.  Classes are more complex.  AFAIK there is no way of doing it with out writing a managed C++ wrapper.

In fact this link: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_managed/interop/article.php/c6867/ seems to agree with me :)

Comment: I've used the technique linked to by @Goz for a couple of years now and it works well. There is a fair bit of time involved in building the wrapper, but a plus is you can turn your C++ code into components and use them in the UI designer with Drag-Drop form building.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a wrapper in *C++/CLI* would be easier to accomplish (IMO) than using *Managed C++*. I've found it quite easy to understand and started with only a cursory understanding of good ol' C++.

Also, the C++/CLI syntax is nicer than the Managed C++ syntax.

I would recommend this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394818) if you go down that road.

Answer (score 0):

C++/CLI is the replacement for Managed C++, and is basically the same thing only better, so I assume your question applies to avoiding C++/CLI also. I think the answer is really no - you have to wrapper it in *some* kind of managed language for C# to access the classes, excepting the COM route.